# How to merge date and time into one datetime column

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have a recently made data.frame that has three columns, Date, Time, and Data. I'm looking to combine the date and the time variables into one Date.Time variable.

My data.frame is called, `data_dataframe` and looks like this:

```
Date     Time   Data
1/26/94  13:00  8.4
```

I tried:

```
as.POSIXct(paste(data_dataframe$Date, data_dataframe$Time), format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

but this didn't work. Reading around didn't seem to help my problem. Any tips?

Comment: `as.POSIXct(paste(data_dataframe$Date, data_dataframe$Time), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` remove `:%S` as there are no seconds in your time.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this which will create a new column with 'New_DateTime'

```
data_dataframe$New_DateTime <- paste(data_dataframe$Date, data_dataframe$Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
data_dataframe$Date <- with(data_dataframe, as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%y"), Time)))
```

After that one can remove the "Time" column; since it is integrated in "Date" 
now:

```
data_dataframe <- data_dataframe[,-2]
```

Result:

```
> data_dataframe
#                 Date Data
#1 1994-01-26 13:00:00  8.4
#2 1989-02-20 11:00:00  7.5
> class(data_dataframe$Date)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

**data:**

```
text<-"Date     Time   Data
       1/26/94  13:00  8.4
       2/20/89  11:00  7.5"
data_dataframe <- read.table(text=text, header=T)
```

Comment: I got this error when I tried that "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"

Comment: I tried copy and pasting this answer and changing the df1 to data_dataframe in both places but am still getting that error

here is what I imput

    data_dataframe$date <- with(data_dataframe,as.POSIXct(paste(as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))))

Comment: @user2920249 Please check exactly what I posted. The inner part of your command in the comment above `as.Date(Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")` is not correct, and it is different from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your format string doesn't match your data. This works, though:

```
as.POSIXct(paste("1/26/94", "13:00"), format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

Comment: I got this error when I tried that "character string is not in a standard unambiguous format"