# Adding Time Stamp to a date in R

Tags: r, date, timestamp, posixct

Hi Have 2 columns in a dataframe. Column 1 has Dates like 2017-01-01 and column 2 has time stamp like 1:00 PM.

I need to create another column that combines these 2 information and gives me the 2017-01-01 13:00:00

Comment: `lubridate::ymd_hm(paste("2017-01-01", "1:00 PM"))`

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359546/converting-two-columns-of-date-and-time-data-to-one and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32784786/how-to-merge-date-and-time-into-one-datetime-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105984/combining-date-and-time-into-a-date-column-for-plotting and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609252/r-tick-data-merging-date-and-time-into-a-single-object and ....

Comment: Yeah sorry i missed that. i used as.POSIXct(paste(x$date, format(as.POSIXct(x$time,format='%I:%M %p'),"%H:%M")), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

Comment: There's no need to convert your date and time column to `POSIXct` before you paste. By pasting you are converting them back to `character` format, only to change it back to `Date` format, very redundant.

Answer (score 5):

Use `as.POSIXct` to convert from character to date format.

```
df$date.time <- as.POSIXct(paste(df$date, df$time), format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M %p")
```

EDIT:

To provide some further context... You paste the date and the time column together to get the string `2017-001-01 1:00 PM`.

You then input the format of the string as a POSIXct argument using `format =`. You can see the relationship between symbols and their meaning [here](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html).

Answer (score 4):

#### Reproducible example

```
library(lubridate)
A <- data.frame(X1 = ymd("2017-01-01"),
                X2 = "1:00 PM", stringsAsFactors=F)

#         X1      X2
# 1 2017-01-01 1:00 PM
```

#### solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
temp <- A %>% 
          mutate(X3 = ymd_hm(paste(X1, X2)))
```

#### output

```
          X1      X2                  X3
      <date>   <chr>              <dttm>
1 2017-01-01 1:00 PM 2017-01-01 13:00:00
```

#### multi-row input

```
B <- data.frame(X1 = ymd("2017-01-01", "2016-01-01"),
                X2 = c("1:00 PM", "2:00 AM"), stringsAsFactors=F)

temp <- B %>% 
          mutate(X3 = ymd_hm(paste(X1, X2)))


#           X1      X2                  X3
#       <date>   <chr>              <dttm>
# 1 2017-01-01 1:00 PM 2017-01-01 13:00:00
# 2 2016-01-01 2:00 AM 2016-01-01 02:00:00
```

Comment: You do not need `rowwise`. You've just confused your `paste` arguments. Try `B %>% mutate(X3=ymd_hm(paste(X1, X2)))` for instance.

Comment: Thanks, my paste argument is messy! I've edited with your help.